# Find and highlight non-Latin code-page characters in a Word document

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have looked for this on the net but unfortunately no joy. I can find a lot of examples of find and replace but not much on find and highlight with `regex`.

What I want to do is look for non-Latin code-page characters in a MS Word document and highlight them. I thought the best approach would be to use `regex` (open to suggestions if that's not the case). Below code high lights the whole document:

```
Sub Highlight_Words()
    Dim oRE As New RegExp: oRE.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9:]"
    Dim oM As Match

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdRed
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = oRE.Pattern
      '.Text = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\s:]"
      '.Text = "[a-zA-Z\d\s:]"
      '.Text = "  "
      With .Replacement
        .Text = "^&"
        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True
      End With
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = True
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

P.S. I am working on Windows 7 (64 bit) and Word 2013

**Update1:**
Below is a sample text :

> This is just a sample text to test highlighting of non-alphanumeric
>   characters (i.e. characters that are not English language characters
>   (i.e. À) and not numbers). There are exceptions to this rule like
>   apostrophe (“2’”) or colon (“:”) or hyphen (“-“). But I can add these
>   exceptions once I have the main pattern to search for non-alphanumeric
>   characters

So from the above sample text, **À** should be highlighted (I did have other characters in the text but unfortunately they are not displaying on the site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use RegEx inside a Word document; RegEx can only run on a string you'd extract from the document (assign to a String variable). But location in the document and any formatting information is lost. Any search must be done using Word's built-in wildcard functionality which is similar to RegEx but not the same and not as "powerful".

Basically, the requirement appears to be anything in the "standard" ANSI codes through ANSI 126, given a "Latin" code page. (You can see the characters and their codes using Word's Insert Symbol (Insert/Symbol, More Symbols) dialog box.

Testing with the provided sample text, this search string works: `[!^011-^0126]`. This searches for anything *not* in the character range ANSI 11 (Word's new line character) through ANSI 126 (lower case z). Additional characters with higher ANSI codes can be appended after `126`, as literal characters.

Put into the code in the question:

```
Sub Highlight_Words()
    Dim Pattern As String

    Pattern = "[!^011-^0126]"   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdRed
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Text = Pattern
      With .Replacement
        .Text = "^&"
        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True
      End With
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = True
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```